# Sequence of HTTP requests in Angular 6 with RxJS

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, concatmap

My objective is to save information in a backend server via POST requests. I need these requests to be executed one by one when the previous one finishes. But I need to add some logic between requests. These requests are made using **RxJs Observables**.

I'll give you some context. My app has 5 models: **Country, State, City, Address, Person.**

A Person has an Address, that belongs to a City, that belongs to a State, that belongs to a Country.

Each model contains its "parent" ID as foreign key (e.g. City has attribute 'state_id').

All the information is available via form. So when I submit the form, I want to save this information in my backend server.

In order to do this, I need to check (via GET request) if the country/state/city/address already exists in the database, if it does I need to bind its ID to the "child", otherwise I need to POST it and then bind its ID to the "child".

How can I achieve this? **I have done some research and tried to do this piping `concatMap()` operators**. But my problem is: how can I `concat` these requests?

This is what I have so far:

```
this.countrySvc.getCountryByName(countryAux.name).pipe(
            concatMap(country1 => {
               if (country1[0] != null){
                    /*Country exists in DB*/
                    countryAux.id = country1[0].id;
                    return of(country1[0]);
                }
                else{
                    /*Country is not in DB, i need to save it before continuing*/
                    this.countrySvc.postCountry(countryAux).pipe(
                        concatMap(country2 => {
                            countryAux.id = country2.id;
                            return of(country2);
                        })
                    )
                    .subscribe();
                    return of(countryAux);
                }
            }),
            concatMap(country3 => {
                console.log("Checking what do I get here: " + country3.name + " " + country3.id);
                return country3;
        })
        )
        .subscribe();
```

I can't figure out how to do this correctly. The sequence of requests I'm looking for is:

```
GET country                     // Search by name
if it exists
    state.country_id = ID       /*ID comes in response*/
else
    POST country                /*ID comes in response*/
    state.country_id = ID

/*Once this (or these) previous request(s) complete*/
/*---------So far i have implemented up to here---------*/

GET province                    
if it exists
    city.state_id = ID
else
    POST state
    city.state_id = ID

/*Once this (or these) previous request(s) complete*/   

GET city                    
if it exists
    address.city_id = ID
else
    POST city
    address.city_id = ID

/*Once this (or these) previous request(s) complete*/   

GET address
if it exists
    person.address_id = ID
else
    POST address
    person.address_id = ID

/*Once this (or these) previous request(s) complete*/   

POST person
```

How can I manage to do that? Note that my main issue is that sometimes I will need to do some POST requests between some GET requests and sometimes I won't. However I'll need to return some Observable (with Country/State/City... data) in each situation to the next operator.

Comment: All this logic should be on the server, not on the client.

Comment: I've changed my code in order to move this logic to the server. Now It works, thanks